# How to upgrade GCC on macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina I have an old, pre-installed version of GCC (4.2.1) that is not compatible with other libraries that I need to use...

How can I upgrade to a more recent version (I need 4.4 at least)?

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Are you referring to the include path at the end? Because other than that it says that it's Clang, not GCC

Comment: If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed on your mac, do 'brew install gcc'. The stable version appears to be [9.3.0](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gcc)

Comment: macOS has an ancient version of libstdc++ that's used when the compiler is invoked as `gcc`.  It uses a recent version of libc++ when invoked as `clang`, so do that.

Comment: @Henri Using Homebrew I get an error (and I have fear to run the commands to overwrite)... `Error: The 'brew link' step did not complete successfully. The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink bin/gfortran Target /usr/local/bin/gfortran is a symlink belonging to apple-gcc42. You can unlink it: brew unlink apple-gcc42 To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files: brew link --overwrite gcc`

Comment: Do what the error message says.